# Swift - tableviewcell returns empty using custom cell

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift programming and would need some help to check what is wrong in my tableviewcell. I have tried alot of great suggestions on stackoverflow.( make sure your outlets are connected, set delegate and datasource of your tableview to self)

This is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit


class CharacterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate , APIControllerProtocol {



@IBOutlet weak var  CharacterInfoView: UITableView!



var apiController:APIController!

var dataArray: [[String:Any]]?

var processcharacter= [CharacterListModel]()



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()




    self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.white

    self.CharacterInfoView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

    self.CharacterInfoView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    self.CharacterInfoView.dataSource = self

    self.CharacterInfoView.delegate = self



    apiController = APIController()

    apiController.delegate=self



    self.navigationItem.title =  "Character"

    self.view.showLoading()



    apiController.getCharacterData{ (statusCode, data, response, error) -> () in

     self.view.stopLoading()



     if(statusCode == nil)

     {

     self.view.showServiceNotAvailableMessage(self)

     }



     if !(error == nil)

     {

     self.view.showServiceNotAvailableMessage(self)

     }



     if statusCode == 200

     {

     do

     {



        self.processcharacter= CharacterListData.processData(data: data)

        self.CharacterInfoView.reloadData()



     }

     catch(_ as NSError)

     {



     }

     }

     else

     {



     return

     }

     }

}



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    if self.dataArray == nil

     {

        return 0

     }

     else

     {

        return processcharacter.count

     }

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Cell", for:indexPath) as! CharacterTableViewCell



    var processcharacters= processcharacter[indexPath.row]

    cell.location.text = processcharacters.location

    cell.name.text = processcharacters.name

    cell.characterID.text = processcharacters.characterID

    cell.time.text = processcharacters.lastlocatedtime



    if wecares.sos == true {

        processcharacters.imagebutton = UIImage(named: "sos_icon")!

    }

    else{

        processcharacters.imagebutton = UIImage(named: "null_button")!

    }



    cell.button.image = processcharacters.imagebutton



    return cell

}

func reachabilityChanged(_ status: Bool) {

 }
```

}

This is my subclass for my ViewController:

```
import Foundation


class CharacterListDataHelper: NSObject {

static func processData(data: AnyObject?) -> [CharacterListModel]

{



    var modelList:[CharacterListModel] = [CharacterListModel]()

    let darr = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as! Data, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [[String:Any]]

    var dataModel:CharacterListModel



    for obj in darr!

    {

        dataModel = CharacterListModel()

        dataModel.location = obj["playerLocation"] as! String

        dataModel.name = obj["playerName"] as! String

        dataModel.characterID= obj["playerID"] as! String     

        dataModel.lastlocatedtime = obj["lastUpdatedTime"] as! String

        }

        modelList.append(dataModel)

    }

    return modelList

}
```

}

This is my Model:

```
import Foundation


struct  CharacterListModel {



var name: String?

var characterID: String?

var location: String?

var lastlocatedtime: String?

var imagebutton: UIImage?



var sos: Bool?
```

}

This is my TableViewCell:

```
class CharacterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var characterID: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastlocatedtime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you set CharacterTableViewCell as the class of the custom cell in the identity inspector?

Comment: @rjmerej Yes. i have set CharacterTableViewCell as the class of the custom cell in the identity inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't fetch data in **viewDidLoad()** method. Fetch in **viewWillAppear** and reload after getting data.

Comment: I tried fetching in viewWillAppear and reload after getting data instead. Still doesn't work. Anything else should i include?

Comment: Put BreakPoint in numberOfRowsInSection And Check are you getting any rows or not.

Comment: 1 row is being returned

Comment: Are you able to see in tableview?

Comment: I could not get it displayed in a tableview. My values are being populated into my model but my cell value remains empty.

Comment: That's strange. Might something is you missing. You should make simple new project with same tableview and static data so you might now where is problem.

Comment: i tried static data as well. Anything in the tableviewcell would be blank.

Comment: I have not tried it yet. How should i implement it in my codes?

Comment: I meant your cell items constraints in storyboard?

Comment: Yes. i set constraints for all my cell items in the storyboard

Comment: Put your Project or sample project in Github which it's no working. i will check it and let you know the reason.

Comment: Its working now! :D I re-looked into the point where you mentioned if there is any rows returned in the numberOfRowsInSection. Apparently it is referencing to the unused dataArray. After linking it to the model, it is able to properly display the cell values now. Thanks alot!